# Merging two csv files if matched column then concatenate extra columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am looking for some assistance with pandas. I am trying to compare the "email" column for any matching and then concatenate the extra columns into a separate csv.

I have the following:

file1.csv

```
email, user_id
example1@gmail.com, 1
example2@gmail.com, 24
example3@gmail.com, 12
example5@gmail.com, 31
```

file2.csv

```
email, group_id
example1@gmail.com, g1
example2@gmail.com, g1
example3@gmail.com, g2
example4@gmail.com, g3
```

output.csv:

```
email, user_id, group_id
example1@gmail.com, 1, g1
example2@gmail.com, 24, g1
example3@gmail.com, 12, g2
```

I appreciate any assistance provided. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Merge

```
import pandas as pd 
f1 = pd.read_csv('f1.csv')
f2 = pd.read_csv('f2.csv')
out = pd.merge(f1,f2,on='email',how='inner')
print(out)
out.to_csv("final.csv", index=False)
```

The output is

```
email   user_id  group_id
0  example1@gmail.com         1        g1
1  example2@gmail.com        24        g1
2  example3@gmail.com        12        g2
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood, you were trying to achieve something like that:

```
import pandas as pd

csv1 = pd.DataFrame({"email":["example1@gmail.com", "example2@gmail.com", "example3@gmail.com", "example5@gmail.com"],"user_id":[1,24,12,31]})
csv2 = pd.DataFrame({"email":["example1@gmail.com", "example2@gmail.com", "example3@gmail.com", "example4@gmail.com"],"group_id":["g1","g1","g2","g3"]})
csv3 = pd.DataFrame({"email":["example1@gmail.com", "example2@gmail.com", "example3@gmail.com"],"user_id":[1,24,12],"group_id":["g1","g1","g2"]})

list_with_dataframes = [csv2,csv3]

result = csv1
for dataframe in list_with_dataframes:
    result = result.merge(dataframe, how = "outer")

print(result)
```

And that gives an output:

```
                email  user_id group_id
0  example1@gmail.com      1.0       g1
1  example2@gmail.com     24.0       g1
2  example3@gmail.com     12.0       g2
3  example5@gmail.com     31.0      NaN
4  example4@gmail.com      NaN       g3
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. All matching data is retained, all missing data is changed with NaN. If you want only fully matched data to be retained simply replace "outer" with "inner" in this line:

```
result = result.merge(dataframe, how = "inner")
```

That gives an output:

```
                email  user_id group_id
0  example1@gmail.com        1       g1
1  example2@gmail.com       24       g1
2  example3@gmail.com       12       g2
```

Comment: How can this be written that it takes the file location of file1.csv and file2.csv as a Dataframe?

Comment: @JeremyLin you could do something like that:
path_to_files = ["path/to/csv2", "path/to/csv3"] etc
and then
list_with_dataframes = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in path_to_files]
If you want to search for csv files automatically in a certain folder, that is also possible. I can update the answer to account for that if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this is as simple as doing a merge:

```
output = pd.merge(left=file1, right=file2, on='email', how='inner')
```

Setting 'how' to 'inner' ensures that only the matches in both files are kept